Is a sphere, whose volume is a sum of volumes of two given constructible spheres, constructible?
If I have two spheres with radius $r_1$and $r_2$ a sphere with the volume as the sum of volumes of these two spheres will have radius $(r_{1}^3 +r_{2}^3)^{1/3}$ now given that $[\mathbb{Q}(r_1):\mathbb{Q}]=2^l$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(r_2):\mathbb{Q}]=2^m$ for some $m,l\in \mathbb{Z}$ will it be that $[\mathbb{Q}(r):\mathbb{Q}]=2^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$?
For more context, we are talking about compass-straightedge constructions, where a number $a$ is constructible if the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ has degree $2^k$ over $\mathbb{Q}$for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$
Simpler versions of this problem where both $ r_1$ and $r_2$ are rational can be disproved by the FLT argument. also if we take out the constraint on $ r_1$ and $r_2$(i.e,not necessarily constructible) we can find examples like $4^{1/3}$ and $4^{1/3}$
For the main problem, I'm not able to find a proof of non-existence or an example of existence. Please help
